# Exception thrown while importing JSS app args.App.ImportUser is null or empty

Tags: jss

I deploy with this command:

```
jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary
```

When I do I get the following error:

```
Exception thrown while importing JSS app
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: args.App.ImportUser is null or empty
Source: Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Pipelines.Import.SwitchUser.Process(ImportPipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Pipelines.Import.ImportPipeline.Import(ImportPipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.ImportService.ImportJob.StartImportInternal()
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this error was because I'd changed : "app name=" in the [appname].config file. To change this you need to change 4 places.

```
[appname].config => <app name="
[appname].deploysecret.config = <app name="
package.json => "config": { "appName": 
package.json => "sitecoreDistPath": "/dist/
```

I would also recommend manually delete all config files from the app_config/include/zzz folder and removing as many traces as possible from the templates/renderings and content for the old app. Also delete the /dist folder files from the IIS folder.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the Sitecore JSS Server Setup, There is a step:
Install the JSS Server Components zip package using the Installation Wizard.

This package also create an User in Sitecore, and Install some config files.

In file:

> \App_Config\Sitecore\JavaScriptServices\Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Apps.config

Is the ImportUser defined:
The default value is:

> importUser="sitecore\JssImport"

So check that this config file exists in the Sitecore webroot and that the ImportUser is filled in.

Also check the config with /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx possible the ImportUser is overwritten by another config file:

An option to fix this could be  re-install the Package. Sitecore JavaScript Services Server for Sitecore

Check your deployUrl in the {appnam}config.json: This should be CM Sitecore sever.

Comment: /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx  shows the importuser, I've also "enabled" the import user from sitecore. The deploy url in scjssconfig.json seems correct. Also I get the message : Sitecore has accepted import task JSSImport-jss-6:04:25 PM